# select the data between two dates from a json data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a json file with data as,

```
[
[1,622,782,783,"2015-04-21"],
[2,622,782,783,"2015-04-21"],
[3,622,782,783,"2015-04-22"],
[4,622,782,783,"2015-04-23"],
[5,622,782,783,"2015-04-24"],
[6,622,782,783,"2015-04-28"],
[7,622,782,783,"2015-04-28"],
[8,622,782,783,"2015-04-29"],
[9,622,782,783,"2015-05-04"],
[10,622,782,783,"2015-05-05"]
]
```

How can I select/load only the values between the dates `2015-04-23` and `2015-04-28`?

Comment: what do you have so far? what have you tried?

Comment: I have a json file named sample.json and when i select `from` and `to` dates using date pickers and when i click submit button, i want to load the data from json between that two dates

Comment: What code have you tried so far to select from the JSON?

Comment: fwiw, Date() function gives values you can compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick option for you here:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-21"],
  [2, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-21"],
  [3, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-22"],
  [4, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-23"],
  [5, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-24"],
  [6, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-28"],
  [7, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-28"],
  [8, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-29"],
  [9, 622, 782, 783, "2015-05-04"],
  [10, 622, 782, 783, "2015-05-05"]
];

var fromTime = new Date("2015-04-23").getTime();
var toTime = new Date("2015-04-28").getTime();

var filteredDates = [];
var row, date;

for (i in data) {

  row = data[i];
  date = new Date(row[4]);

  if (date.getTime() >= fromTime && date.getTime() <= toTime) {
    filteredDates.push(row);
  }
}


var results = document.querySelector("#results"); // debugging
results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredDates); // debugging
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Date.parse() function which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Then you could make the compare as comparing integers.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var data = [
  [1, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-21"],
  [2, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-21"],
  [3, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-22"],
  [4, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-23"],
  [5, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-24"],
  [6, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-28"],
  [7, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-28"],
  [8, 622, 782, 783, "2015-04-29"],
  [9, 622, 782, 783, "2015-05-04"],
  [10, 622, 782, 783, "2015-05-05"]
];

    var date1 = Date.parse("2015-04-23");
    var date2 = Date.parse("2015-04-28");
    var length = data.length;
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i< length ; i++){
        if(Date.parse(data[i][4])>date1 && Date.parse(data[i][4])<date2){
                      result.push(data[i]);
                      }
    }
           alert(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

you could check it in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hobf634a/)